# trying to get a oauth token using fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I've been following Scott Allen's ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals on pluralsight, and can successfully request a token, using a simple HTML page, but now need to try and do this using fiddler. the reason I need to test it using fiddler, is that this is in essence the way my apu will be called. An ios device app is being written, and i have to do the api piece.

So, i enter the followdin in fiddler:

HEADER:

```
 POST http://localhost:53140/token HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    Host: localhost:53140
    Content-Length: 50
```

BODY:
    grant_type=password:

```
{"userName":"something",
"password":"password"}
```

and I get a 400 - bad request.

i've changed the content type to : application/x-www-form-urlencoded but still a 400.

what am i doing wrong?

***EDIT***

Even tried "username=username&password=password" still no joy

***EDIT***

Whoops, had the grant_type in the wrong place. this needed to be in the body:

grant_type:password&username:username&password:password

Now i get username or password are not valid:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or
>   password is incorrect."}

i'll leave the post active, as this may be a red herring.

Comment: In "grant_type:password&username:username&password:password", you have ":", it should be "=" like "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password"

Comment: Also, in fiddler, make sure after grant_type=password&username=username&password=password there is no space or line break.

Comment: Please fix up the typos in your post; right now it's clearly incorrect and you're sending people on a wild goose chase trying to guess which problem you're having.

Comment: EricLaw, can you not see the edits?

Answer (score 9):

In fiddler, make sure after grant_type=password&username=username&password=password there is no space or line break.

Comment: This may be an old thread, but after hours of trying to do the same as the OP, it was a simple as this for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was troubleshooting the same error message

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}
```

while trying this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) myself. It seems that the `UserName` being persisted onto the local database is actually the email address rather than the `UserName` provided in the JSON payload while invoking the `/api/Account/Register` Web API. You can verify this by running a T-SQL query against the [AspNetUsers] table. (If you are using LocalDb database, you can open the database located in the project’s App_Data using Show All Files.)

Please note that once the actual user name is confirmed as the email address, the email address (and possibly your password) has to be URL encoded when posting the `/api/Token` request.
**For example:**

```
grant_type=password&username=Alice%40yourdomain.com&password=_Password123
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well spotted, this has been foxing me for past half hour :)

Comment: yeah, username must be the email address

Answer (score 4):

In fiddler you can write
Host: localhost:17271
Content-Length: 81
**Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8**

In RequestBody you can write
**grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123&response_type=token**

Hope to someone help it because my problem is solve by this type of requestbody

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it using Fiddler4 (this guide assumes you are starting from scratch):

1. Create a new MVC Web API 2 project in Visual Studio 2015
2. Ensure you set the Authentication to individual user accounts (assuming this is what you want)
3. Once the project has loaded build the project and start the Web Application to ensure it runs
4. You should get the default "ASP.NET Getting started..." page with the navigation links at the top "Home" and "API".

At this point I tend to change the "DefaultConnection" in my Web.config file to point to an actual SQL Server where I will host the ASP.NET Identity tables but you don't need to just use the localDb by default.

1. Fire up Fiddler4 and then click on the Composer tab on the right

   [image]
2. Change the request type to 'POST' and then change the URL to that of your local website which you ran earlier (the VS Web API 2 project) e.g:

   http://localhost:49598/api/Account/Register
3. Change the header text to the following:

   User-Agent: Fiddler
   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
4. In the request body you need to compose your JSON data that will be the account you are registering for example:

   {
     "Email": "youremail@account.com",
     "Password": "YourPassw0rd!",
     "ConfirmPassword": "YourPassw0rd!"
   }
5. With your website running hit the Execute button at the top right

   [image]
6. If successful you should see a 200 response on the left hand side of Fiddler4 which confirms the Account Controller API action Register was called a new user was successfully registered.
7. Now you can test your user account by requesting an Authorization token.  Clear the contents of the Request body in Fiddler4 and then change the type to POST if required.
8. Change the header text to the following again:

   User-Agent: Fiddler
   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
9. In the request body paste the following (changing the values for your account obviously)

   grant_type=password&username=your@account.com&password=Passw0rd!
10. Hit Execute again and you should see a 200 response on the left hand side of Fiddler4:

    http://localhost:49598/Token
11. Double-click the response to open up the Inspector tab on the right hand side of Fiddler4 which should display the authorization information in JSON format (you can also see it as raw by click on the 'Raw' tab).
12. Look for the 'access_token=' line which will have the access token you need to make "bearer" type requests.

**In layman terms this is what happens now:**

a. You authenticate and get an auth token.

b. Any/All requests made to the API endpoints are done using the bearer token type and this is set in the header of your request.

c. You pass in the auth token you received and this is validated and your request is processed.

d. You should ensure your Web API 2 endpoints have the [Authorize] decoration on the methods and/or class to ensure those areas are secure.

e. If your auth token has expired (set in the App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs class 'AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan'...) then you will need to handle this for example my app calls a dumb method that requires authorization, if that fails the client side AngularJS code redirects the user to the login screen where a valid user can request another auth token by logging in.

*note: I keep the expiry times to 30 minutes for my auth tokens

Okay now to use that token in Fiddler4...

1. Start Fiddler4 and in the Composer tab on the right change the type to GET (Clear the contents of Request Body if you need to)
2. Change the header text to the following:

   User-Agent: Fiddler
   Host: localhost:49598
   Authorization: Bearer  your_very_long_auth_token_here
3. Change the url to the good old api/values endpoint:

   http://localhost:49598/api/values
4. Hit the Execute button and if everything was successful you should see the 200 response on the left:

   200 HTTP    localhost:49598 /api/values
5. Double click this response and the inspector tab should open showing the JSON response

   [image]

This concludes how to use Fiddler4 to test Oauth2 with Web API 2.  Hope someone finds this useful if you spot any mistakes let me know in your comments and I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see is that it looks like you putting the username and password in the Request Body as a Json string. it should just be text with no quotes:

grant_type=password&username=UserName&password=PassWord

Then making sure you have the Content Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Scott's course, but normally for OAuth2, you do a GET request to the `authorization server` with the credentials, which then gives you an `AuthorizationCode` which you then POST along with some other stuff to the `token server` to get your token.

I'm not aware of a shortcut where you can get a `token` by just passing the credentials to the token server.

Comment: Hi Darrel, this is using the new Web API 2 template. i just need a token, so that I can then validate a user. i'm not yet concerned about authorization servers.. :-)